# FCM FireBase Using Token

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-cloud-messaging

I want to generate a notification using Firebase FCM to a specific user's device using the Device token in Kotlin. Anyone can help me to provide the code or any project so I can easily implement it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do similar thing

First  make retrofit instance and call api

```
 fun getInstance():Retrofit{
        return Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(baseUrl).addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build()
    }

    fun getApiService(retrofit: Retrofit):RetrofitApi{
        return retrofit.create(RetrofitApi::class.java)
    }
```

In this way retrofit instance create and now call api

```
interface RetrofitApi {

    @Headers("Authorization:key=${Helper.FCM_SERVER_KEY}","Content-Type: ${Helper.CONTENT_TYPE}")
    @POST("fcm/send")
    suspend fun sendNotification(@Body pushNotification: PushNotification):Response<ResponseBody>

}
```

In activity call this below

```
private fun push(user: User,title:String,message: String) {
        CoroutineScope(Dispatchers.IO).launch {
            val data=mapOf("userName" to user.userName,"title" to title,"message" to message)

            val response=Helper.getApiService(Helper.getInstance()).sendNotification(
                PushNotification(user.token,data, mutableMapOf("priority" to "high"))
            )

            withContext(Dispatchers.Main){
                if(response.isSuccessful){
                    Toast.makeText(this@AddNotificationActivity,"Notification send successfully !",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    finish()
                }
                else{
                    Log.e("noti","${response.body()}")
                    Toast.makeText(this@AddNotificationActivity,"Notification not send , something went wrong !",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Replace Server key with own key and replace Content_Type to "application/json"